# Android - Trying to create a 'Save file first?" Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

My application consists of a list of text files. Clicking a file will load it into an EditText. I created an option menu to save the open file, or save as if working on a new file. What I want to do is show a "Save first?" confirmation dialog if the user tries to open a new file without saving the open file first.

As you can see in my code below I created a boolean variable called changed initially initialized as false. I'm trying to use a TextChangedListener to change changed to true then handle it with an if/else statement in the list's file open code. The problem I'm having is that once I open a file and then try to open another it shows the "Save first" dialog but no matter whether the file is changed or not or whether I click ok or cancel it won't open any other files.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private List<String> items = null;
public File currentDir = null;
public File currentFile = null;
public EditTextLineNumbers et; // My EditText
public boolean changed = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        checkExternalStorage();
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/My Webs");
        currentDir = dir;
        et = (EditTextLineNumbers) findViewById(R.id.ide);
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                changed = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                changed=false;

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        if(dir.isDirectory()) {
            getFiles(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/My Webs").listFiles());
        }else{
            dir.mkdir();
        }
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId()== R.id.newsite){
                Log.d("New Site","New Site was clicked");
            }else if(item.getItemId()== R.id.newfile){
                Log.d("New File","New File was clicked");
            }else if(item.getItemId()== R.id.savefile){
                String temptxt = et.getText().toString();

                if(currentFile!=null){
                    Log.d(currentFile.getAbsolutePath(),currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    String tempfname = currentFile.toString();
                    saveFile(tempfname, temptxt);
                }else{
                    saveFile(null, temptxt);
                }

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        int selectedRow = (int)id;
        if(selectedRow == 0){
            getFiles(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/My Webs").listFiles());
        }else{
            File file = new File(items.get(selectedRow));
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                currentDir = file;
                getFiles(file.listFiles());
            }else{
                currentFile = file;
            if(changed==false){
                try {
                    et.setText(new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next());
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                }else{
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                    alert.setTitle("Save first");
                    alert.setMessage("(Will be saved in the current working directory)");

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      String tmpText = et.getText().toString();

                      try {
                        File tempfile = new File(currentDir, currentFile.toString());
                        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempfile);
                          writer.write(tmpText);
                          writer.flush();
                          writer.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                      }
                    });

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                      }
                    });

                    alert.show();

                }
            }
            }
        }


    private void saveFile(String sFileName, String sBody){

        if (currentFile!=null) {
            try {
                File saveDir = new File("/");

                File tempfile = new File(saveDir, sFileName);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempfile);
                writer.append(sBody);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            saveAs();
        }

    }

    private void saveAs(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Save as");
        alert.setMessage("(Will be saved in the current working directory)");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          String value = input.getText().toString();
          String tmpText = et.getText().toString();

          try {
            File tempfile = new File(currentDir, value);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempfile);
              writer.write(tmpText);
              writer.flush();
              writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
          }
        });

        alert.show();
    }
        private void getFiles(File[] files){
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
            items.add(getString(R.string.goto_root));
            for(File file : files){
                String filename = file.getName().toString();
                String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
                String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
                Log.d("Extension", extension);
                items.add(file.getPath());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_item, items);
            setListAdapter(fileList);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `change` will always be `true` if the text changed, because the event `beforeTextChanged` will be called first and right after `onTextChanged` will be triggered.

> **beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)**
>   This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start are about to be replaced by new text with length after.
>
> **onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)**
>   This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before.

You should **reset** the variable `change` to false after you save the file

```
if(!changed){
    // open the file
 }else{
    changed = false;
    // show the alert and save the file
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `et.setText(new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next());` you change the text. At this point, changed becomes `true`.

You need to set it back to `false` after you have loaded the test in the EditText.